# How to access Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder on a Windows Mobile device?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

During my app's runtime, I'm saving some data in txt file to location: Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
On Windows 10 PC, I can easile read this file in C:\Users\marcin\AppData\Local\Packages[app id]\LocalState\
How can I access this file, when I run the app on a phone? When I connect my device to a PC, I don't see an option to access AppData folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Access App Data, You need Device Portal first. Below are the instructions from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal).

1. Head to the Settings App > Updates and Security > For Developers, and
   enable Developer Mode and Device Portal.
2. Type the IP address displayed below the Device Portal options into your favorite web
   browser.

   - Make sure you’re on the same network, otherwise your browser
     won’t be able to find your phone.
   - You’ll also need to authenticate
     yourself with the device.
3. Make sure you’ve got an app sideloaded (or
   sideload one now using the “Apps” page).
4. Click on “File Explorer” to
   see the tool above.

See [This Link](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/06/08/using-the-app-file-explorer-to-see-your-app-data/#rv0SJob9wBC18DkE.97) for Full info as to how to access App Data

Comment: Thank you ver much. Unfortunately it turns out that "App File Explorer" feature was introduced in Anniversary Update. I have Lumia 920, so I've got a build of Windows 10 that is about a year old, so I can't access this folder.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you've side-loaded the app you can access it via the Device Portal.

To access the device from a PC enable the Device Portal in the "For Developers" section in Settings. Connect the device to the PC via USB and navigate to the device portal in the browser at http://127.0.0.1:10080

See [Device Portal for Mobile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal-mobile) and [Windows Device Portal overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/device-portal) on MSDN for more details.

If you've deployed through the store then there is no external way to access the app's data. The easiest would be to save it in the RoamingFolder instead of the LocalFolder and then read the data from the PC side. Another option would be to provide a sharing feature in the app to share the log file via email, etc.